# "Class Not Found" Error with JUnit Test in IntelliJJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have been getting the error `Class not found: "org.jpl7.test.TestJUnit"Empty test suite.` when trying to run a JUnit test on my project in IntelliJ. I see that a lot of other people have also experienced this problem, but I have found not solution to mine in their answers.

This project is one I have forked from GitHub, the Java-to-Prolog project from SWI-PL. Their file-structure may be playing into this, as I suspect my problem may have to do with source paths.

This is their file structure

packages-jpl

----src

--------c

--------java

------------org.jpl7

----------------All non-test source files

----------------test

--------------------All test files

Currently, the Source Path for src is set to the "java" directory, and the Source Path for Test is set to the "test" directory. The content root is set to "packages-jpl", since that is the directory that contains the idea folder and such.

The problem may also lie in my output paths. My main output path is set to "\production\packages-jpl". My Test Output Path is set to "\test\packages-jpl".

Answer (score 0):

Try marking:

- The java folder in the main directory as the **Sources root**
- The java folder in the test directory as the **Test Sources root**:

[image]

And try to keep the same package structure in both main and test directory.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the file structure. In this project, the test folder is nested within the src/java folder. That is the way it was when I cloned it from github. I would prefer to maintain the same file structure for the sake of pull requests.